# Custom widgets in Composite C1

Tags: c#, custom-component, c1-cms

I'm in the early stages of a new web project for quite a large site, and the chosen CMS is Composite C1. I'm so far satisfied with it, it's promising and I can work relatively fast with it.

However I'm currently stuck on, in my eyes, a simple problem.

The project will handle a lot of products (6000+) from an external database, along with a lot of product groups (hierarchical). This in it self is not a problem, but through the CMS the editors of the website will be able to add meta data to a product, create web specific groups of products, etc. This is where the problem starts.

In the simplest of worlds a single product selector on a custom data type would be sufficient, but with 6000+ products this is not an option. So I would like to create a custom Widget with either auto completion or a search field + result field (when adding Data to my custom Data Type).

After reading [How to add custom widget to C1?](http://docs.composite.net/Console/ConsoleFAQ?q=How%20to%20add%20custom%20widget%20to%20C1?) I thought it would be a smaller problem, but I can't even get the code sample to work. I'm getting a Configuration Error saying

> **Parse Error Message**: Type 'SampleProvider.MyWidgetFunctionProvider,
>   WidgetProvider' could not be created

The SampleProvider.MyWidgetFunctionProvider are in a separate project in the same solution and all references are set. What could be the problem?

When/if I can get the custom widget functionality to work, what would be the best way to handle the reference to my external entity? Can you spot any problems with the solution I've come up with?

TL;DR; I need a way to create meta data for entities from an external database in Composite C1, without using the standard Selector widget (too much data for the Selector). What should I do?

Best regards,

Comment: I am busy learning about Composite myself and will also be needing to do the same thing you are doing.  Hopefully an answer comes before I get to this point, otherwise you will have another head working towards a solution.  :)

Answer (score 0):

I have created the same also.Its working fine for me.

I hope you have registered dll with same application name and name space

> SampleProvider.MyWidgetFunctionProvider, WidgetProvider

This error may be caused by the namespace given

Just see this format is given type="Namespace_name.Class_name, Assembly_name" and name is an assembly name.

If the answer is not clear i can help as the same code is working perfect for me